# How to add new route dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to add new route to router dynamically at runtime when the router has been initiated? For example user types something in input and after that I create a new route.

Comment: Please include an example of the type of route that you want to be able to add. The answer is probably no but that you can do this another way, but I need to see what you're trying to do in order to be certain.

Comment: @PaulS now i am just making a small tutorial and this question has occured, for now i don't have practical example. I just worried if it is possible i.e. in case if server due to some conditions sends you a banch of new routes... but yes, maybe there are no real-life cases for runtime routes creation

Comment: Generally what you'll want to do is what Glenn Reyes described in his answer, which is to use a route param that can be any value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use *[route params](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)*.

Here is a brief example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, Link} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Link to={`/${this.state.value}`}>{this.state.value && `Go to /${this.state.value.toLowerCase()}`}</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Page = (props) => (
  <h1>{props.params.term}</h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/:term" component={Page}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector('#app'),
);
```